# Remove "<em> edit Article </em>" and [current-page:pager]

Tags: meta-tags

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site in which I'm using Meta tag module for SEO purpose. I have configured the meta-tags global and content settings.

When I try to edit a node for a content type, for example, edit an Article, inside the meta tag section in the page title field, it always displays *`<em> Edit title </em>`*, even I have removed all the tokens for this field but it still displays these tokens.

These are the global and content configurations.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

This is how it displays the page title field inside the meta tags section in the content node edit page.

> [image: screenshot]

I want to remove *`<em> edit Article </em>`* and *[current-page:pager]*.

Comment: You are trying to edit content node edit page, which in fact copies the global page. You should have similar `Page title` global setting field, remove tags there.

Comment: Hi @AltaGrade! I have removed it from Global Page title field also, you can see the above placed image for Global settings.

Comment: Maybe you are editing a node that was saved before you changed Meta tag setting. Does the problem persist if you try to create a new node?

Comment: yup, you are right, it's not displaying for new nodes, is there any way to delete it from all previous nodes?

Comment: Since we found what the problem was, please accept my answer below and I will try to help you further.

Comment: So how many pre-existing nodes you have? If not many then it's better to edit them manually. If a lot, then you will have to research if it can be done with VBO module or dive into coding a custom module.

Comment: Here's a lot of nodes needs to edit, can I edit these nodes using VBO module?

Comment: VBO is mostly for mass editing nodes' cck fields, so I am not sure if works with meta tags, but install and give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed removed tags in global and content settings, then they should not appear when creating new nodes. What you are looking at is probably a node that existed before you changed the meta tag settings.

Comment: Hi @AltaGrade, can you help me regarding this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/259413/73356 please?