# The node from one content type doesn't appears in Nodequeue

Tags: views, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7 and nodequeue module with Royalslider.All other content types are working fine but only one content type which is named as **Real Estate Listing** doesn't show it properly.

Here's even it's available in queue list:

[image]

and here's how it's displaying in slider:
[image]

All of other content type nodes it displays all queues as:

[image]

But for Real Estate content type node it displays only 2 queues as:

[image]

What can be wrong?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to admin/structure/nodequeue/
2. Click 'edit' for the nodequeue in question.
3. Check 'Real estate' under 'types'.
4. Save.

Comment: Hi @Jaypan, can you take a look at this question:  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/259701/73356   please?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: It was checked already but the issue was coming from somewhere else.