# Why does a node appear in two slides?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site with the Nodequeue module installed. I have a content type named *Real Estate Listing*, and I need to display a nodequeue for this content type inside the royalslider slider on its main page.

This is the Real Estate Nodequeue.

> [image]

This is the view for this nodequeue.

> [image: screenshot]

When I have added a node to this nodequeue, it appears twice on the slider:
In the first slide, it displays correctly; in the second slide, only the title and other fields appear, without CSS applied.

This is the screenshot of the first slide.

> [image: screenshot]

This is the second slide.

> [image: screenshot]

I added this node only once in the queue. Why does it appear in two slides? What can be wrong?

> **Updated:**
>
> [image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please note that in a site about Drupal, we don't need *Drupal* in the question title. Since the site it is about Drupal, all titles should contain *Drupal*. At that point, what would the point of having *Drupal* in the titles be?

Comment: This is possibly related to your royalslider configuration. Is the node appearing twice in your Views preview?

Comment: Hi @prkos, you are right, in Views preview the node appearing only once. How can I check the configuration of royalslider?

Comment: It seems to be under Configuration > Media. I've never used it but I expect you'll have at least one instance created that is being used. Maybe you have it set to display one slide that shows big image, and other information you see is the "thumbnail" which would become apparent if you add more nodes. Also if you're using royalslider with Views slideshow there may be one more place to check the settings ;)

Comment: I think here's the Views Header or something Above content have been used to display this nodequeue views. AS I have added an updated image, take a look please!